# Correctly erasing an element from a vector

Tags: c++, vector

If I have a table of vectors declared as

`vector<int> table[9][9]`
and I want to compare and delete the element if it already exists, would the deletion be:

```
for(int row = 0; row < 9; row++)//erases the current choice from the whole row
 {
   for(int h = 0; h < (int)table[row][k].size();h++)
   {
     if(table[row][k][h] == table[i][k][0])
     {
       table[row][k].erase(table[row][k].begin() + h);
      }
    }
  }
```

I thought this would work, but I'm not 100% because I tried to delete every element using this technique and it didn't work, for those of you who want to see the code I used to delete all the elements, then it is:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
for(int k = 0; k < 9; k++)
      for(int n = 0; n < table[i][k].size();n++)
        table[i][k].erase(table[i][k].begin + n);
```

this method did not work, so I used clear instead.

Comment: If you erase an element the next element will have the same index. (Hence decrement the index or use a while and increment the index only if no element is erased)

Comment: But anyway erasing one element at a time is unnecessarily inefficient.

Comment: I'm not using C++ 11 so I cannot do many of the declarations I want to. I used clear, which did remove all elements, but I'm wondering why erase did not even though I looped through each element in the table.

Comment: @user3251195: for the reason Dieter says. First you erase the element at index 0. After doing that, the element that previously was at index 1 is now at index 0. Then you erase the element at index 1. You never erase the element now at index 0.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what `choice` and `k` are, but to erase all values from a vector `v` that are equal to a particular value `val` use the "erase-remove idiom":

```
v.erase(
    std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), val),
    v.end()
);
```

Hence, to do this same thing for all vectors in `table`:

```
for (auto &row : table) {
    for (auto &v : row) {
        v.erase(
            std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), val),
            v.end()
        );
    }
}
```

If you have a more complicated condition than equality, use `remove_if` in place of `remove`. But in your case, the extra condition involving `puzzle` doesn't use the loop variable `h`, so I think you can test that before looking in the vector:

```
if (puzzle[row][k] == 0) {
    // stuff with erase
}
```

In C++03 you can't use "range-based for loops" `for (auto &row : table)`. So if you don't have C++11, or if you need the index for use in the `puzzle` test, then stick with `for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)`.

Comment: why not std::for_each instead of the index based loop?

Comment: @Joky: mainly because the questioner has code that works for that part. I only mentioned the range-based for loop because I wanted to cut and paste my erase-remove code unmodified, and it saved writing `auto &v = table[i][k];` or similar :-) Also because using `for_each` requires writing a separate functor, but that's a style issue. Personally I don't think it aids readability to move a short loop body out to another place in the source file.

Comment: I was also reluctant to std::for_each for this reason before lambdas :)

Comment: @Joky: my feeling is that basically I didn't use `for_each` in C++03 because the lack of lambdas made it inconvenient for what it does, and I don't use it in C++11 because range-based for loops are usually even more convenient for what it does. It has occasional uses, where it somehow overcomes the inconvenience.